# UIScrollView cuts empty space at the bottom

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, storyboard, viewcontroller

[image]

I cannot scroll below that red line, it seems, that UIScrollView automatically cuts it out. How can I make it not cut it out?

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are asking for. If you can give more explanation, it'd help others trying to answer. Also, can you make your views different colors and post the image here? (make your scrollview, the view it is contained in, different colors)

Answer (score 2):

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

This line seems to fix it, at least in my case. Content View is a child of Scroll View.